# Send IE 7 (and below) to old/sub directory of site. <!-- [if IE 7]><"LINK TO OLD SITE"/><![endif]-->

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have just launched a site (using Joomla and a custom template), which doesn't display that well in IE7 (and I guess below too). I have looked around and have found out that you can link to different style sheets from my index.php, however, instead of linking to a different style sheet, I want it to link to the older site which is still live (under `www.mydomain.com/old`).

Is that at all possible?

As stated in the title, I have looked around and found out that you could use an if statement like this -

```
<!-- [if lte IE 7]><"LINK TO OLD SITE"/><![endif]-->
```

is what I'm trying even possible? I haven't got anywhere with it so far, trying the usual html tags of `href="http://www.mydomain.com/old"`

Any help would be great on this. I'm just getting stuck at the moment!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time. Additionally, the simplest way to start a new paragraph is to hit *Enter* twice.

Comment: `All the tags have left my head` There's a _huge_ button in the nav bar labelled "tags" where you can look them up like everyone else!

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=meta+refresh+0

Comment: Browser-specific redirects date back to the mid-90s.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I did see the tags, but I didnt see a [php] tag, and that is what this is written in. I have maanged to change it to this - <!--[if IE 7]>You are using an outdated browser, please <a href="domain/old">click here</a> to view our old site<![endif]--> - which works, but I would prefer for it not to display IE8/IE9 page, and just redirect to the "old" site! thanks to everyone, and sorry for the tags....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional comments are used in the client-side part of your page, and so are not useful for PHP.  You can use a conditional comment with JavaScript like this:

```
<!— [if lte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href = "http://www.mydomain.com/old";
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

The disadvantage of this is that you are performing this task on the client machine, which is slower than if you performed the redirect on the server and sent to user to a different page instead.  You can do this using PHP by checking the browser version and redirecting with `header`:

```
$browser = get_browser();
if($browser->browser == 'IE' && $browser->majorver <= 7) {
    header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/old');
}
```

Bear in mind that for this to work you must call `header` before any data is sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've used the php version, and it does exactly want I want! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, much reasonable would be to catch IE7 users before they started to render the page.
So it could be done with server-side script either with some mod_rewrite. Would be easier and faster.

Comment: yes, this is what I want.. See my above comment! I'm now looking into the below answer. Thanks for your kind response!

Comment: You did not get it. I've meant that more correct to use server-side (mod_rewrite, php, etc.) way neither client-side (js, html).

Comment: yes, sorry, Thats where I wrote i'm looking into the below answer from shanethehat - I'm trying their php answer..  that would be a better way, no?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have another answer below that why I was confused. Yes, php method should works better.

Answer (score -1):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H76.html).

> The objective of this technique is to enable redirects on the client side without confusing the user.
>
> ...
>
> In HTML and XHTML, one can use the meta element with the value of the http-equiv attribute set to "Refresh" and the value of the content attribute set to "0" (meaning zero seconds), followed by the URI that the browser should request.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
  <head>      
    <title>The Tudors</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://thetudors.example.com/'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>This page has moved to a <a href="http://thetudors.example.com/">
      theTudors.example.com</a>.</p> 
  </body>  
</html>
```